# How to run only specific method from test suite

Tags: python, selenium

I have a test suite with multiple methods in it. Is it possible to run only one method from the test suite ?

```
class TestSuite()
    def setUp():
        ...

    def test_one():
        ...

    def test_two():
        ...
```

<strike>I tried following</strike>

```
python testSuite.py.test_one
```

with no luck.

**UPDATE**

To be more precise about the context, I try to launch Selenium functional automated tests written in python against a website.
To execute a given test suite, i run (from a virtual environment)

```
test.py testSuite.py
```

Is it possible to launch only a specific method declared in the testSuite.py file ?

Comment: which unittesting framework you are using?

Comment: @GaurangShah I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `Class Name` also  :

```
>>> $ python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

In your case, it would be like

```
>>> $ python -m unittest test_module.TestSuite.test_one
```

Other way round, Add `@unittest.skip()` to skip the particular test case

In below case, `test_one` will not excecute

```
@unittest.skip()
def test_one():
    ...

def test_two():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this would be:

`file.class.method`. In your case:

```
testSuite.TestSuite.test_one
```

Answer (score 0):

make an object of `TestSuite()` class then you can call method whichever you want.

```
 class TestSuite()
    def setUp():
       ...

    def test_one():
       ...

    def test_two():
       ...

TestSuiteObj = TestSuite()
TestSuiteObj.test_one()
```